# pgAdmin 4 Not connected to the server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I've installed Postgresql 11 and pgAdmin4 (version 4.5) and while I'm able to create tables in a new database, if I attempt to SELECT or INSERT into those tables I always get a message 'Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.' in the "Messages" tab in pgAdmin 4.

If, however, I open the SQL Shell I can execute a SELECT on a table that I've attempted to insert into from pgAdmin and it shows that the rows have been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem with 4.5 & 4.6. Postgres 10 server on Ubuntu, PG Admin on Windows 7. I downgraded PG Admin to 4.3 and it works.